# AmberTools 19 のインストール時に 'Wrong compiler' エラーが表示される

Tags: macos

Mac OS 10.15, miniconda 2.7.16 の環境で、AmberToolsのインストール用ディレクトリを
`user/apps/amber18/` に指定し、下記サイトを参考に `./configure` を実行しました。

[AMBERとAmberToolsのインストール方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Ag_smith/items/d2e86dda17f190a3dd0f)

この時以下のエラーが出てきてしまい、解消法がわかりません。
解決法がわかる方いらっしゃるでしょうか？

```
Your AMBERHOME environment variable is not set! Auto set it to: 
/Users/makoto/apps/amber18
Checking for updates...
Checking for available patches online. This may take a few seconds...

Available AmberTools 19 patches:

No patches available

AMBER_PREFIX=/Users/makoto/apps/amber18
AMBER_SOURCE=/Users/makoto/apps/amber18

Using the AmberTools miniconda installation in /Users/makoto/apps/amber18/miniconda
version 2.7.16

Obtaining the gnu compiler suite versions, e.g.:
     gcc -v
The C version is 11.0.0
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1

ERROR: Wrong compiler. You specify compiler=gnu but actually using clang
Please change compiler option to clang, or set correct PATH (or CC, CXX) to GNU compiler
```

Answer (score 0):

すいません、頭をリフレッシュして改めてコマンドラインを見直したら解決しました。
スクリプトを実行していた所を以下の通り変更したらちゃんと実行されました。

**変更前**

```
./configure -noX11 -macAccelerate gnu
```

**変更後**

```
./configure -noX11 -macAccelerata clang
```